# Specific L1 piece-wise linear approximation of the convex function of one variable

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory

Consider a convex function $f(x)$ of one variable $x$ on some interval $[a,b]$.

**Question:**
What is known about the L1 approximation of $f(x)$ by piecewise linear functions? How to construct approximation for the prescribed number of nodes?
Are there some algorithms and/or theoretical results?

Moreover let us impose additional conditions on approximation - as shown on figures below - values of approximation at nodes (and $a,b$) should be equal to values of $f(x)$, or saying in the other way:  approximation should be pointwise less than or equal to the function.

Geometrically it means that we need to find a piecewise linear curve such that the area under it is most close to area under $f(x)$, in the other words areas of sectors are minimal.

If one needs to find only one node one easily derives a clear geometric
solution - to place node at point $x$ where tangent is parallel to the chord between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. (See figure 1).
If we have many points it gives condition connecting node with neighbouring nodes, so one might think about nodes as about some system with pairwise interaction.

I have some dynamic programming algorithm, but I guess much should be known.

Figure 1: Red - best one-node approximation - node at point where tangent is parallel to chord

[image: Figure 1: Red - best one-node approximation - node at point where tangent parallel to chord]

Figure 2: Approximation with two nodes

[image: Figure 2: Approximation with two nodes]

Comment: I guess you are asking how to choose the node locations and values, when the number of nodes is prescribed.  And I guess you also require that the "approximation" be pointwise less than or equal to the function.  If so, you should make these things clear in the question.  At present, it's very hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Thank you for your comment. I will revise question. Indeed, your remarks are fully correct:  I want to know node locations when number of nodes is predescribed and  moreover I am interested in specific situation when values of approximation at nodes are the same as values of "f" or saying like you wrote: "approximation" be pointwise less than or equal to the function"  - as it is shown on figures.